# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'validators'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-validation

I want to  validate `phone_number` in my form with `RegexValidator`
I find this validator in here and it works all right in model.py but in `forms.py` I get this error
can any one help me? 
here is my `model.py`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

#additional
blood_type = models.CharField(max_length=2,blank=True)
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
case =models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

and this is `forms.py`:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")

class Meta():
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('case', 'blood_type', 'phone_number','description')

    labels = {
        'description': '',
        'case':'',
        'blood_type':'',
        'phone_number':'',
    }
    widgets = {
        'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Phone number'},validators=[phone_regex]),
        'blood_type': forms.Select(choices=BLOOD_TYPES),
        'case': forms.Select(choices=CASE),
        'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'customtext', 'placeholder':'Please write your ilness...'}),
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *widget* normally has no validators, a form *field* has, like a [**`CharField`** form field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/) can have validators:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = forms.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('case', 'blood_type', 'phone_number','description')

        labels = {
            'description': '',
            'case':'',
            'blood_type':'',
            'phone_number':'',
        }
        widgets = {
            'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Phone number'}),
            'blood_type': forms.Select(choices=BLOOD_TYPES),
            'case': forms.Select(choices=CASE),
            'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'customtext', 
            'placeholder':'Please write your ilness…'}),
        }
```

That being said, normally that is not necessary since a `ModelForm` will perhform validations defined in the model.

Comment: Thank you very much and thanks for quick answering.